# How to generate entity in IntelliJ using persistence?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I met a problem when I tried to generate entity in IntelliJ. Database is MySQL. The problem is the table contains the type `datetime`. I remember that I used to generate it, the `datetime` is convert to `TimeStamp`. But this time when I used IntelliJ it became to `Object`. So how to set it to `Timestamp`? I post the print to help you understand what's going on.
[image]

Comment: Of cause I can set it one by one, but it's not convinent

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same problem with Datetime types

Comment: @RaymondHolguin check my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, see [Java Persitence/Basic Attributes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes).
It's not a basic type of hibernate, so idea could not find the mapped type for it. It matches object type default. It is easy to solve, just change the type to the one you want, and click ok to genernate

Comment: I know the reason now. But it's still complex

Comment: I've to set them one by one. It's waste time

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's IntelliJ IDEA's bug. When I switch to version 1.4, it did a good job. Maybe it's the Version1.5's bug.